# Nice Excel Reports from Python - How

Tags: python, excel

At present I have some analytical processes that run in SAS and create excel reports (the client needs excel reports, it is a requirement). Using ODS excel SAS produces nice looking tables with headers and such

I am able to change the processes to Python (some of the reasons are we are emigrating to Hadoop/Spark which we will access through Python), I mean the data extraction from the source, and all the data manipulation and summarization. However I have not found a library (yet) that can easily write to excel a nice report

I see from multiple sources that one can loop through the desired output to be sent to excel and place it in each cell, formatting as needed. And no doubt that this is what ODS excel likely does. Perhaps use pandas to write the data quickly and then use openpyxl to do the formatting (or just use openpyxl for all) - this seems like a lot of work (I guess for the cost of SAS license you get nice utilities that do the hard wrk for you among other things)

My question is if someone can point to a library that automates most of this and creates nice reports (clients do not just like numbers and words in cells - that is the reality). I can of course write my own functions (I can also likely write functions for a lot of stuff I just use modules/libraries). I will be generating the excel files in Unix, hence I do not have access to office in the same system.

I am asking again, because the one question with most answers 7 years old

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. Unfortunately,  questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Perhaps you can go through R as an intermediary. Since R is closer to SAS than Python is, there is more of a chance of finding a ready-made library for doing what you want. Perhaps this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/importexport-data-to-and-from-xlsx-files/

Comment: Thanks, I know R quite well, it is however not so well supported at work and I can't do much about it. I do not think R and SAS have anything in common though

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of problem domain rather than language. Both R and SAS are designed with statistical data analysis in mind.